# Http call in angular2 for PHP not working

Tags: php, angular-http

Iam writing the code to make http call to php web-service in angular2. There's no error in console, however no o/p is shown.
 My code are as follows:

hero.service.ts

```
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost/ex/ex1.php';

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
             .toPromise()
             .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
             .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }

}
```

ex1.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$arr = array(
    array("id" => 1, "name" => "Rajneesh"),
    array("id" => 2, "name" => "Rahul")
);
echo json_encode($arr);exit;
?>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { Hero } from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>ss</h1>
        <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
            {{hero.name}}
        </div>
        `,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
    heroes: Hero[];

    constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getHeroes();
    }

    getHeroes(): void {
        this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = 
     heroes);
    }
}
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: For any one concerned: Implemented it the way given on "https://thinkster.io/tutorials/angular-2-http". It works

Comment: Hi what do you get back when you call the url  private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost/ex/ex1.php';
  You can use the browser or and http-rest client like postman to see what is returned to the client.